# How to set scrollbar position in TWebScrollBox?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, tms, tms-web-core, delphi-12-athens

I have a [`TWebScrollBox`](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebscrollbox/) component on my TMS WEB Core form with a couple of `TWebButton` components above the `TWebScrollBox`. When you click on the buttons, then I want to take the user to specific locations on the `TWebScrollBox` component.

My IDE code completion shows me that I can do:

```
MyScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position := 420;
```

But this doesn't work when I compile. When I compile my app, then I get the following error:

> [Error]: identifier not found "Position"

So `Position` exists in code completion during design-time, but isn't actually there when I try to compile.

How can I set a scroll position for the `TWebScrollBox`?

Comment: TWebScrollBox uses a descendent of TControlScrollBar (which is Delphi in the VCL.Forms unit).  This is why you have see it in  code completion - but that doesn't mean TMS is using it.  Per their forums, to scroll use `WebScrollBox.ScrollLeft: integer;
WebScrollBox.ScrollTop: integer;`